# Facebook Api - Login and get cover image

Tags: php, facebook, api

i'm currently trying to wrap my head around this as it's my first time using the Facebook API, essentially i just want my php to grab the image link of the users cover photo to display it on a standard php page, i've set it up to display the cover link as text but i'm not getting anything.

I've googled and searched stackoverflow but i can't seem to find anything, here's my current code:-

```
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);

    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
}


function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '000000000000000',
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true, 
        version    : 'v2.1'
    });


    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
};


(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!' +
        response.fields=cover;
    });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `cover` is not one of the standard fields a call to `/me` responds with, you have to ask for it specifically using the `fields` parameter …

Comment: `response.fields=cover` makes absolutely no sense there … there is no variable named `cover` in that scope, and you have to specify fields while _making_ the API request, not by trying to manipulate the response afterwards … `/me?fields=cover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Facebook depreciated the Username reference for the API, so there's no specific way to do it through the API or through the graph.

The only way i managed to do it is by creating an input field for them to generate their content from the username they put in, thanks anyway guys